# How to implement GenericRepository and UnitOfWork with Identity.EntityFrameWorkCore and My own entities together

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-identity, unit-of-work

I am facing a challenge while implementing a generic repository with a unit of work pattern in my ASP.NET Core project. The issue arises when I attempt to inherit from IdentityDbContext in my custom MyBlogDbContext, causing the following error:

ERROR!!! : CS1503 : Argument 1: Cannot convert 'MyBlogDAL.Context.MyBlogDbContext' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.IdentityDbContext'.

To provide some context, I've included a snippet of my generic repository implementation below:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MyBlogDAL.Context;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal;
using MyBlogDAL.Repositories.Abstract;
using MyBlogDomain.Entities;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyBlogDAL.Repositories.Concrete
{
    public class GenericRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        
        protected readonly DbContext Context;

        public GenericRepository(DbContext Context)
        {
            this.Context = Context;
        }

        public async Task AddAsync(T entity)
        {
            await Context.Set<T>().AddAsync(entity);
        }
```

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to effectively integrate Identity with a generic repository, or if there's an alternative approach to achieve the desired functionality.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Can I see your inheritance?

Comment: As Nima said: we need more code and details. Like what does your MyBlogDbContext look like?